# mklink /d locked out after reboot

Tags: windows-11, mklink

Both PC are having the same User name, but different password.

PC-1: TestUser / pwd1
PC-2: TestUser / pwd2

Reproduce problem:

1. From PC-1 explorer, click on PC-2 and key in TestUser/pwd2
2. Create a link by `mklink /D \Test \PC-2\Test
3. Reboot
4. Try to access the link again, will get the error message below.

[image]

In windows 7, it will at least prompt for User ID / Password.